# Создать ссылку на главной yii

Tags: yii

Всем привет. вопрос мб повторяется,но не нашел.может искал плохо
вообщем
есть сайт на yii лэндинг
цель добавить политику безопасности в низу.где-нашел.
в админке создал страницу с текстом. на главной написал текст и теперь нужно сделать ссылку чтоб при клике перехадило на страницу. 
НО я не знаю УРЛ к странице policy(которую в админке создал) ((
можно /href...ссылка..текст
в любом случае ссылку не знаю( 
подскажите плиз

Comment: может поможет:) http://site.ru/adminPath/controllerName/actionName

Answer (score 1):

```
  <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true) ?>/index.php/department">админка цехов</a> <br>
```

оно?